# Making a bprintfn (StringBuilder.AppendLine vs Append)

Tags: f#

I need to print a bunch of command-line help.  There is a bprintf, but oddly no bprintfn for working with StringBuilders.  I soon realized you can't add anything (like "\n") automatically because the (format:PrintF.StringFormat<'a, unit>) parameter has to come last.

Finally got this working with kprintf.  It seems like this would be useful.
Am I overlooking a builtin way of doing this?

```
module helper =
    let bprintfn (sb : StringBuilder) =
        Printf.kprintf (fun s -> sb.AppendLine s |> ignore)


module Command =
    
    let printMan arg =
        let sb = StringBuilder()
        let a format = helper.bprintfn sb format
        
        a "Title"
        a ""
        a "body1 %s" arg
        a ""
        a "body2"
        a ""
        a "footer"
        
        sb.ToString()
```

Comment: I think they just didn't implement it. You can submit your version as an enhancement.